# What's SQL Server's analogue of MySQL's unicode_ci collation?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, collation

As far as I understand, in MySQL unicode_ci (utf8_unicode_ci in particular) collations are meant to support all the characters regardless to locale.

I need to achieve the same with SQL Server 2008 R2. My database is going to contain data in very different languages (not limited to latin-based alphabets). I am not going to use non-Unicode strings at all. What collation should I chose?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might as well go with Latin1_General_CI_AI

The reason is that unicode data is stored using NVarchar fields, SQL Server is more flexible in that it can mix Varchar (1-byte) and NVarchar (2-byte) data.  So to match UTF8, **any** collation would do.  As for CI - every single collation in 2008 allows for the CI specification to be added (it is a checkbox in the UI "case sensitive" - unchecked for insensitive).

The last bit and some others like width are just additional tuning on SQL Server.

Point #2 from http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748

> utf8_unicode_ci is fine for all these languages:
>   Russian, Bulgarian, Belarusian, Macedonian, Serbian, and Ukrainian.

If you require sorting for a particular language, where languages handle accents differently, you need a specific dictionary order - refer here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx.  Otherwise Latin1_General is based on Latin-US

Comment: "You might as well go with Latin1_General_CI_AS" - do you mean that in this case cyrillic text is going be collated correctly as well as East and West European Latin?

Comment: @ivan Even the MySQL utf8_general_ci does not handle multiple languages.  It you need language specific sorting you need to pick a language specific collation.

Comment: All the language specifics I need is that Б is meant to go after А (etc.) in Cyrillics as well as B after A in Latinics. Nobody knows and bothers about how accents are to be sorted - ä after or before á. AT the same time Cyrillic alphabet should go after Latin alphabet and digits should go before Latin alphabet. My database is going to contain values in English, Italian, German, Greek, Turkish, Hungarian, Norwegian, Finnish, Russian, Bulgarian, Belarusian, Macedonian, Serbian, Ukrainian, Polish, Romanian, Vietnamese, etc in the same column (some times even in the same one string).

Comment: The application logic relies heavily on SQL (SQL Server is used not just as a storage, but does (in stored procedures) even more applicationary work than middleware), so server-side encodings and collations do matter.